# Angular 7 and firestore, get data from another collection that corresponds to each document on another collection

Tags: angular, join, collections, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

What I am trying to do list equipment belonging to each client.

I have read up, watched videos, result to copy and paste but nothing is working, and my head is spinning.

I need the id's with each client and equipment, so I am grabbing them like this

```js
fetchJobs() {
  this.todoCollectionRef = this.afs.collection('clients');
  this.todo$ = this.todoCollectionRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => {
    return actions.map(action => {
      const data = action.payload.doc.data() as Todo;
      const id = action.payload.doc.id;
      return {
        id,
        data
      };
    });
  }));

}


fetchEquipment() {
  this.equipmentCollectionRef = this.afs.collection('equipment');
  this.equipment$ = this.equipmentCollectionRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => {
    return actions.map(action => {
      const data = action.payload.doc.data() as Equipment;
      const id = action.payload.doc.id;
      return {
        id,
        data
      };
    });
  }));

}
```

I have also tried to re-think my data structure, but because each client will have multiple items and not all the same amount, I have tried with arrays with maps but unable to update details.

If someone can please point me in the right direction I will be grateful.

[image: Screenshot]

I think I need something like this..

```js
  this.todoCollectionRef = this.afs.collection('clients');
    this.todo$ = this.todoCollectionRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => {
      return actions.map(action => {
        const data = action.payload.doc.data() as Todo;
        const id = action.payload.doc.id;
        return this.afs.collection('equipment', ref => ref.where('client', '==', data.client)).valueChanges()
        .pipe(map(eqip => Object.assign({}, {id, data, eqip})));
    });

})).switchMap(observables => Observable.combineLatest(observables));

      }  
If anyone can help here I would be truly grateful.
And if someone could explain the code to help me and others learn.
```

Comment: what you are actually want to do? clear your point

Comment: what i am am tying to do is list clients ( thats done) then query the second collection for equipment belonging to that client and list each peice of equipment on the same page,  so I was thinking I would query by the clients name,  so my collection1.doc will have name, adddress, phone number and so on, then collection2.doc will have name, make, model, serial and so on.

Comment: I will screenshot when I get to a computer in hopes it will provide a clear goal.

Comment: try to store equipment with clients id and when you want to query for equipment retrieve data against client id by using .where() function .
if you don't know how to query  using .where() ill post an answer for you.

Comment: what I have been trying is asf.collection('equipment', ref => ref.where('clientname', '==' this.name));

What I am looking at doing is passing the client name from the client collection to the equipment one.

this is what I am stuck ok.

I can do this if I use a button to pass the name to the equipment, but i am looking for a way to not pass the name via a button.

Comment: Updated my code a little

Comment: I would like to say thank you, I have got it now, by using prams and setting id on the object. then using where ==,   I was trying to merge the two items into one array but this was not needed, just had to think outside the box and duplicate data on firestore.

Comment: great work . keep it up

Answer (score 0):

With the function of fetchEquipement you are using the collection of 'client' you should use **this.equipmentCollectionRef**

Comment: This was a typo on my part when creating the post, have amended my post.  Thank you

Comment: I am unable to list the equipment belonging to each client, how do I get just the details for the said client listed with the other details?

I will need to be able to get the id of the equipment.